# Is there any way to change response type of Adobe Omniture tracking?

Tags: adobe-analytics, google-chrome-os

We are using **Adobe Omniture** for analytics in our app. To track an event, Omniture uses `pixel tracking` which responds an image. Since, we are working on a ChromeOs app and as per security policies, ChromeOS does not allow to load images from external url. Is there any way to change response type of Adobe Omniture tracking?

Comment: This is not currently possible with the Adobe Analytics AppMeasurement (javascript) library. However, you can use Adobe's [Data Insertion API](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/data-insertion/c-data-insertion-api) and build your own request URLs/payloads and get an xml response signifying success/fail

Comment: Thanks, I will check that too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are other options out there for you. All of them are outlined here:

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/reference/developer.html

Notably, you can:

- Use server-side code, like Java or PHP
- Data insertion API
- Data Sources, meaning you collect the data yourself then import it via a spreadsheet into Adobe Analytics